# Get $_GET from a redirected URL

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I have an URL that redirect to itself but with a $_GET parameter. I'm trying to get this $_GET variable starting from that first URL. I tried:

- curl with the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION
- Open the url with file_get_contents

But i still cant get my hand on this variable... Of course you can do it manually by typing the URL in the address bar and waiting for the redirection but i would like to do that in command line.

The starting URL is:
http://jukebox.delicieuse-musique.com/

If you have any idea i would be glad to hear them!

```
$url = "http://jukebox.delicieuse-musique.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_exec($ch);
$urlN = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

echo $urlN;
```

gives me :

> http://jukebox.delicieuse-musique.com/

Comment: Provide your full curl code.